# Removing Convert.ToDecimal Dependency (Dependency Injection)

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, solid-principles

I am currently learning dependency injection to create more maintainable code with MVC. I am already injecting a model and a calculator service to my controller instead of having a to new up dependency.

I have a few Convert.ToDecimal calls in my constructor, and didn't know if I needed to worry about using dependency injection to remove the static method call which is a DI design smell. Is removing that going too far?

```
private readonly ICalculationService _calculation;
private readonly ICalculatorModelService _calculatormodel;

public CalculatorController(ICalculationService calculation,
    ICalculatorModelService calculatormodel) {
    _calculation = calculation;
    _calculatormodel = calculatormodel;
}

public ActionResult Index() {
    var model = _calculatormodel;
    return View(model);
}

public PartialViewResult Calculate(string submit, string txtValue, 
    string value1) {
    var model = _calculatormodel;
    if (submit == "+")
    {
        if (Session["value1"] == null)
            Session.Add("value1",Convert.ToDecimal(txtValue));
        else
            Session["value1"] = value1;
    }
    else if (submit == "=")
    {
        if (Session["value1"] == null)
        Session.Add("value1", 0);

        model.Result = _calculation.Calculate(Convert
            .ToDecimal(Session["value1"]), Convert.ToDecimal(txtValue));
    }

    return PartialView("_Calculator", model);
}
```

Comment: What you are thinking about dependencies on types `string`, `decimal`?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. Currently the code has a dependency on the Convert .Net class.

Comment: It mainly depends on how easy the code will be to test and maintain based on the dependency.  If it's easy to test and maintain while calling the static function, there is not much gain injecting it.  But if it is hard to test and maintain, you should inject the dependency because then you can stub it in tests.

Comment: Thank you for the response Caleb. It was helpful. I am happy to be learning!

Comment: Read about the difference between [stable and volatile dependencies](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/ploeh/archive/2006/08/24/718828.aspx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand the question, you are worried about the static call of `Convert` and you ask if this class should also be injected.

If that's the case, you don't have too. Same goes for similar static calls like `Math.` methods etc.

The rule I follow for such .NET helper calls is, if the call is deterministic, i.e. always returning same output for the same input, then go ahead call it (anyway you depend on .NET framework, right?). But if the call is non deterministic, like `Datetime.Now` or use of `Random` class, then I inject these dependencies (which makes code more testable, of course)

Comment: That makes complete sense to me. Thank you for breaking it down. I like your answer!